# Which video encoding algorithm should I use for a video with just one static image and sound?

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding

I'm doing video processing tasks and one of the problems I need to solve is choosing the appropriate encoding algorithm for a video that has just one static image throughout the entire video.

Currently I tried several algorithms, such as DivX and XviD, but they produce 3MB video for a 1 minute long video. The audio is 64kbit/s mp3, so the audio takes just 480KB. So the video is 2.5MB!

As the image in the video is not changing, it could be compressed really efficiently as there is no motion. The image size itself (it's a jpg) is just 50KB.

So ideally I'd expect this video to be about 550KB - 600KB and not 3MB.

Any ideas about how I could optimize the video so it's not that huge?

I hope this is the right stackexchange forum to ask this question.

Comment: Perhaps you can set the frames-per-second or bitrate to be incredibly low. Or perhaps there is a compression scheme which has keyframes, of which you can eliminate all but two (start and end).

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @ninjagecko If I set bitrate to incredibly low, the image in the video also gets incredibly low quality. I settled with 300kbit/s for the video. Good thinking about frames-per-second! Let me experiment with that right away. (Not sure how it will work with the audio though.)

Comment: @ninjagecko It worked pretty well! Thanks a lot. After changing FPS to 1, I got the final size down to 2MB! That's a 33% improvement. I wish I knew how to work with keyframes.

Comment: @bodacydo: can you set the FPS to something like 0.5 or less?

Comment: @ninjagecko Wow! It looks like I can. The video is now 1.2MB! This is fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the frames-per-second to be very low. Lower than 1fps if you can. Your goal would be to get as close to two keyframes (one at the start, and one at the end) as possible.

Whether you can do this depends on the scheme/codec you are using, and also the encoder.

Many codecs will have keyframe-related options. For example, here are some open-source encoders:

lavc (libavcodec):

> keyint=<0-300> - maximum  interval  between  keyframes  in  frames  (default:  250  or  one keyframe every ten seconds in a 25fps movie.
>
> This is the recommended default for MPEG-4).  Most codecs require regular keyframes in order to limit the accumulation of mismatch error.  Keyframes are also needed for seeking, as seeking is only possible to a keyframe - but  keyframes  need  more  space  than  other frames,  so  larger  numbers here mean slightly smaller files but less precise seeking.  0 is equivalent to 1, which makes every frame a keyframe.  Values >300 are not recommended as the quality might be bad depending upon decoder, encoder and luck.  It is common for MPEG-1/2 to use values <=30.

xvidenc:

> max_key_interval= - maximum interval between keyframes (default: 10*fps)

Interestingly, this solution may reduce the ability to seek in the file, so you will want to test that.

Comment: That's fantastic ninjagecko. I didn't know FPS can be fractions. I thought they can only be integers. I'm trying values as low as 0.1 and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to the implementation of video encoder, not the video encoding standard itself.

Actually, most video encoder implementations are not designed for videos of static image, thus it will not produce perfect bitstream as we imagined when a video of static image is inputted. Most video encoder implementations are designed for processing "natural" video.

If you really need a better encoding result for video of static image, you may do a hack on an open source video encoder, from 2nd frame on, mark all MBs' as "skip"...

Comment: MB means MacroBlock. A MacroBlock is generally a 16x16 square, the video encoder will split the input image into MBs, and then process them one by one.